# How to flip flop image in mac osx application

Tags: image

I am working with an app for Mac OSX for latest version and want to flip flop,re size,drag,lazy loading for image.I can do that in iPhone iOS,but i don't have any idea about, how to perform that operation on Mac OSX.I am new to that type of application,Help is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIPS at the command line:

```
sips -f horizontal image.jpg     # flip horizontal

sips -f vertical image.jpg       # flip vertical

sips -r 90 image.jpg             # rotate 90 degrees
```

But actually ImageMagick is miles better and works on all platforms, not just Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your response,But I want to perform that action using objective c and any API of Apple for mac.

Comment: please somebody tell me,is their are any Mac osx API for flip-flop and rotation of image.